# Hibernate: apply filtering by certain column for all requests to database

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate-criteria

In my database I have data belonging to different users.
In the code, requests to the database are made by different ways:

- using Criteria:

  - from one place in code (common parent DAO)
  - from many places in code (children DAOs)
- using HQL queries:

  - same two approaches

Now, I want to be sure, that any programmer, whatever way he makes requests to DB, won't be able to make a mistake and forget about filtering data from any table by `user_id`. The value is a current user's `id`. (If a table doesn't have such column, meaning its data should be accessible for all users, then filtering should be ignored).

Ideally, this filtering would be performed automatically somewhere on a deeper level, rather than in code we write and rewrite. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? The programmer can either query or verify the entity class to check whether the table has user_id column.

Comment: @Lathy The problem _is_ that a programmer has something to do for an entity class (each) - query of verify. He may forget to do it. The price of error - violating of users' data security.

Comment: Get the metadata of the entity class that is being currently used which will give you the properties used in it and you can iterate the property to find whether this entity has user_id and based on the result you can apply the filter.

Comment: The above can also be generalized with the help of interceptors/aop

Comment: @Lathy That very generalization is the subject of my question.

Comment: You are using Hibernate, hibernate has the notion of `filter`s which you define on an entity. Then when those filters are enabled the query will automatically be modified. You automatically enable filters you might want to use some AOP. I used this with multiple projects and it works like a charm, all of your queries are now automatically modified with the requested filter. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html .

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

1. Create a class called UserInterceptor which extends EmptyInterceptor
2. override the getEntityName method.
3. Get the Entity Class metadata. (You may inject sessionFactory into       EmptyInterceptor).
4. Get the properties and iterate it and get the user_id
5. Override onSave method and check for the user_id in the final query generated by HQL.

This may not be the ideal solution but this way we can achieve your requirement.